# How to add / remove elements from array that is in Request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, request

My request looks like  this

```
Array
(
  [name] => Eugene A
  [address] => Array
    (
        [billing] => Array
            (
                [address] => aaa
            )
        [shipping] => Array
            (
                [address] => bbb
            )
    )
)
```

I need to delete the shipping address. But how?

I can only delete both addresses,

```
$request->request->remove('address');
```

but I don't want it.

I want to delete only shipping address, like so

```
$request->request->remove('address.shipping');
```

But it is not working for me

Laravel 5.6

**Update**

Why do I need it?

Easy. I have abstracted out my Form Request validation into a class that is a child to `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`.
I actually have few classes for validation. I call them one by one in a controller like so:

```
app()->make(CustomerPostRequest::class); // validate Customer information
app()->make(AddressSaveRequest::class); // validate Addresses
```

Why?

Now I can Mock this requests in unit-tests, and I can have my validation abstracted out. And I can use Address validation in many places.

But Now I need more flexibility. Why?

Because AddressSaveRequest rule looks like this

```
public function rules(): array
  {
    return [
        'address.*.address'    => [
            'bail',
            'required',
            'string',
        ],
   ...
```

It validates all addresses.
But sometimes I don't want to validate shipping address, if the the chech_box - ship_to_the_same_address is ticked.

But I have my Address validator abstracted in separate file and it is used in many places. There are places where ship_to_the_same_address tick box is not presented.

Thus I cannot use `'required_unless:ship_to_same_address,yes',`

And I cannot use

```
app()->makeWith(AddressSaveRequest::class, ['ship_to_the_same_address ' => 'yes']);
```

Because Taylor [said](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18271) `...when calling makeWith. In my opinion it should make a new instance each time this method is called because the given parameter array is dynamic.`. And it does, and it does not work correctly with `app()->instance(AddressSaveRequest::class, $addressSaveRequest);` and cannot be mocked in unit tests.

Why Taylor decided it - I seriously don't know.

PS
And yes, I know that mocking requests is not recommended.

Comment: unset($request->address['shipping']);

Comment: @Demonyowh,  `ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Indirect modification of overloaded property Illuminate\Http\Request::$address has no effect`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were trying to add or remove inputs from the Request itself:

You can add data to the request pretty easily by merging it in and letting Laravel handle which data source is being used:

```
$request->merge(['input' => 'value']);
```

That will merge in the input named `input` into the input source for the Request.

For removing inputs you could try to replace all the inputs without that particular input in the replacement:

```
$request->replace($request->except('address.shipping'));
```

Just one idea to try.

Comment: This is pretty neat indeed! Cool idea. Got to remember this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$request->except(['address.shipping']);
```

Details: [Laravel Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests)

Comment: I don't need to export data from request.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has a helper method called `array_forget`, which does exactly what it sounds like:

```
$requestArray = $request->all();

$newArray = array_forget($requestArray, 'address.shipping')
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-forget)

After the edit to the main question with why some inputs of the request are to be deleted, my main answer isn't correct anymore. User [Lagbox has the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607805/1336174) for the question that was asked.

However, I would like to note that another solution would be to have seperate Request classes with validation. One for placing an order (assuming it is a system where someone can order stuff) where `ship_to_same_address` is present and another one for things like updating your account, like `PlaceOrderRequest` and `UpdateAccountRequest` classes.

Comment: since this function expects an array, what is the outcome in regards to the Request object `$request`?

Comment: @lagbox You're right! I need to save it to a new array, let me change my answer.

Comment: Maybe I am reading the post wrong, but it seems they want to add / remove inputs from the Request itself, might need clarification

Comment: I don't need to export data from request.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev Can you update your question with your intentions? Because right now it seems unclear why you wan't to remove one item from the request.

Comment: "why" is a big thing. Let me put it in

Comment: 'Why' section is added to the question.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev I added some information. Maybe it will help, maybe not. But Lagbox's answer is the right one to go with I'd reckon.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan, thank you for taking time to read my update question. Your answer is exactly what I ended up with before looking for a way to fiddle with $request. Now I see a way of merging this requests into one and leave the rest to a controller. I mean it is a good solution, but there are other options. Thank you.